# Private Route in react native not working on page changes. The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, vue.js, redux, routes

while click on any function and push to another page in react native but it does not working.for eg logout it does not work while logout.

The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Home'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.

```
let handleLogout = async() => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('AccessToken');
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('isLogin', "false");
    await navigation.navigate('Login');
  }


<Button transparent onPress={handleLogout}>
      <Text>Logout</Text>
 </Button>

<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}>
           {isSignedIn === "true"? ( 
            <> 
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Bookorder" component={Bookorder} />
             </> 
           ) : (
            <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```